# How much does Azure APIM charge if I am using it for just an hour and then delete it?

Tags: azure, apim

If I create an Azure API Management service in my subscription (I select SKU Developer that cost 48$/month via [this official website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/api-management/#purchase-options))
I used it for 1 hour. And then I deleted my Azure APIM right away.

Question is:
Do I get charged for only 1 hour using Azure APIM ?
Or Do I have to pay a total of 48$ once I created APIM in my subscription?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete API Management after one hour of deployment you'll only be charged for a single hour of use. In the US that's currently $0.07 / hour for the developer SKU. The [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=api-management) is great for pricing questions like this.